# Access 2007 Wizards won't run

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

Every time I try to run a Wizard in Access 2007 a dialog box pops up saying the following:

> The database cannot be opened because the VBA project contained in it cannot be read. The database can be opened only if the VBA project is first deleted. Deleting the VBA project removes all code from modules, forms and reports. You should back up your database before attempting to open the database and dlete the VBA project.
>
> To create a backup copy, click Cancel and then make a backup copy of your database. To open the database and delete the VBA project without creating a backup copy, click OK.
>
> [OK] [Cancel] [Help]

(Yes, it's probably overkill to write out the entire message, but there it is.)

When I click [OK] Another dialog box pops up saying:

> This feature isn't installed, or has been disabled.
> ...

However, I have installed every Access 2007 feature, including the wizards.  In fact, earlier this Spring I used the wizards in another project and I haven't made any changes to my Office setup since then.

I have searched stackoverflow and the rest of the web but haven't come up with any solution to this problem. Does anybody have any ideas?

Thanks a lot.
--Knute

P.S. This also happens when I go to "Office Button"->"Access Options"->"Add-ins" and then try to select "Access Add-ins" in the "Manage:" combobox.

#### Update:

The problem happens with more than one Access database.  I don't think it has anything to do with the actual Access database I'm working on because, as I added in my P.S. above, I see the same message when I try to manage my Access Add-ins through the Options panels (a feature that's not linked to any particular database).  Does that make sense?

I uninstalled & reinstalled Access 2007 but did not uninstall & reinstall all of Office. I still have the problem.  Any other ideas?

Comment: I just encountered such a message in A2003 at a client's yesterday. I figured I needed to install the advanced wizards, but when I ran the Office installer from Control Panel | Add/Remove Programs, it showed they were all installed. I aborted the install, and then when I opened Access again, it worked. You might try a REPAIR and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the solution to this.  A poster on [this www.utteraccess.com thread](http://www.utteraccess.com/forums/showflat.php?Wizards-not-working-&Number=1881069) helped me figure it out.  I had installed & uninstalled the 2010 Technical Preview awhile back and it apparently left an incompatible version of **C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VBA\VBA6** on my machine.  By deleting this folder, then restarting Access, I forced Office to run a repair installation.  After the repair, my wizards started working again.  Thanks for your suggestions, Tony.

Answer (score 1):

Does this happen with only one Access database file or multiple?

If multiple try re-installing Office/Access 2007.

If just one then check your references to see if there's anything wierd in there.  Also try importing into a new MDB/ACCDB and/or a decompile. [Decompile or how to reduce Microsoft Access MDB/MDE size and decrease start-up times](http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/decompile.htm)

Answer (score 1):

I too was having this issue complete with the history of having uninstallaed Office 2010 Technical Preview. I am running a Lenovo X61 Tablet PC running Windows 7 64-bit mode. I found the broken VBA files here:

**C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VBA\VBA6**

Same solution: Delete the **VBA6** directory.

The next time I ran Access 2007 it automatically went into its setup routine (a couple of minutes) and when it was done everything was working correctly.

Note: Uninstalling and re-installing Access 2007 did not solve the problem. I had to remove the bad directory as noted in bold above.